# Document in MongoRepository not deleted with 'expireAfterSeconds'

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I would like my `MongoRepository` in Spring Boot to automatically delete documents at a certain point in time after creation. Therefore I created the following class:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;

public class MyDocument {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private String name;
    @Indexed(expireAfterSeconds = 0)
    private LocalDateTime deleteAt;
}
```

Then, I save it in the Spring Boot `MongoRepository`:

```
MyDocument doc = modelMapper.map(myDocumentDto, MyDocument.class);
LocalDateTime timePoint = LocalDateTime.now();
timePoint = timePoint.plusMinutes(1L);
doc.setDeleteAt(timePoint);
docRepository.save(doc);
```

I periodically query the repository and would assume that after one minute, the document will not be there anymore. Unfortunately, I get the document every time I query and it is never deleted.

What am I doing wrong?

The document is persisted as follows (.toString()):

```
MyDocument{id='5915c65a2e9b694ac8ff8b67', name='string', deleteAt=2017-05-12T16:28:38.787}
```

Is MongoDB possibly unable to read and process the `LocalDateTime` format? I'm using org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.10.1.RELEASE, so JSR-310 should already be supported as announced in 2015 here: https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/26/what-s-new-in-spring-data-fowler

Comment: Spring changes it to `Date` when you define this as `LocalDateTime` before persisting in MongoDB. It works for me in Spring 1.10.2-Release version. Can you make sure indexes get created ? You can check by running `db.collectionname.getIndexes()` from mongo shell

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#timing-of-the-delete-operation and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#expiration-of-data. Confirm type of the field:  from mongo shell `db.collection.findOne({}, {deleteAt:1})`

Comment: Thanks for the hints. The field type is correctly denoted as `ISODate(...)` but I see that there is no index created - just the default `_id` is present. Do I have to do anything else than just add the `@Indexed` annotation in a class in order to have indexes generated? I already tried deleting the collection and have it recreated but the indexes won't be added anyway.

Comment: @AlexBlex @Veeram, I think I solved it by adding the `@Document` annotation. Now indexes are created upon startup of the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could fix the issue:

First of all, `java.time.LocalDateTime` is no problem with Spring Data / MongoDB. 
For clarification, add a name to an index, e.g. `@Indexed(name = "deleteAt", expireAfterSeconds = 0)`. This step might not be needed though. However, adding the `@Document` annotation helped a lot:

`@Document(collection = "expiringDocument")`

When I delete the whole collection while my application is running, a new document insert will create the collection again but without the indexes. To ensure indexes are created, restart the application.